# two's complement concept of 1000(Binary)

Tags: binary

In two's complement suppose we have `0000`

1st step INVERT so, `1111`

2nd step ADD 1 therefore, `10000`

goes to 5th bit and is not anymore in a nibble

how to keep it in 4 bits to get -8(i.e. `1000`)?

Comment: Bits that overflow are simply "lost", so your `10000` is really just `0000`, i.e. `-0 == 0`, as you would expect.